# Banner responsivo iframe de google publisher tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

estoy tratando desde hace días hacer un banner publicitario responsivo ya que en las diferentes versiones el banner que anexare en un momento, no se redimensiona si no que se queda con las mismas dimensiones 1070 x 100, un dato **importante** es que este banner viene de un Google pusher tag, que se genera desde Google ad manager, el siguiente script es el que me pide google agregar al header

```
<script async src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/tag/js/gpt.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.googletag = window.googletag || {cmd: []};
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
      googletag.defineSlot('/21634834598/Banner-1070x100', [1070, 100], 'div-gpt-ad-1586132958546-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
      googletag.enableServices();
    });
  </script>
```

y este fragmento se agrega en donde quiero que se vea el banner, que básicamente es un div que tiene otro script, ya intente agregar css al **iframe** para intentar modificar el tamaño sin éxito.

```
<div class="main-container-banner" id='div-gpt-ad-1586132958546-0'>
    <script>
        googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-1586132958546-0'); });
    </script>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No creo que se pueda ya que viene con sus propias dimensiones dicho banner, podrías buscar en la documentación si existe algunas dimensiones mas pequeñas, en donde estas mostrando tu código? en un WordPress por ejemplo? si es así , podrías intentar modificar el HTML , mediante css y añadir la etiqueta !important.

intentaría por css probando esto, así solo tomaría el ancho disponible por cada pantalla

```
#'div-gpt-ad-1586132958546-0'
{
   max-width: 100%
}
```